# Looking for the name of some "rules" which one can declare to be playing by at the start of a debate

Tags: phrases

When you say "I am playing by x rules", x being the word I can't recall, it essentially means you forfeit the right to get upset/offended at or by anything anyone may say as you have given them permission to prioritise getting the information across in the most efficient and accurate way over how it may make you feel.

Comment: All that comes to my mind is the [Marquess of Queensberry Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquess_of_Queensberry_Rules), which may be referenced metaphorically and humorously, but are if anything the opposite...

Comment: The Chatham House Rules are intended to promote openness, but not to this extent.   https://www.chathamhouse.org/about-us/chatham-house-rule

Comment: I just happened across it one day, thought I had bookmarked it as it was quite interesting....hadn't. I'm sure it's someone's name like "fitchers rules " but not that because I've tried that. It seems very obscure and my google skills are not working.